# How to find out if a link is disabled using QTP

Tags: qtp

Is there a way to find if a link is disabled in QTP? for textboxs and buttons it is easy, we can use GetROProperty and then give the property as disabled or ediable, etc. But in the case of links there is no such property which can show that it is disabled. How can we find out if it is disabled or not.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK disabled links are not part of HTML, you can have disabled edit fields (different types of `<input>`, `<textarea>` and `<fieldset>` to name a few) but not links.

If the application you're testing has disabled links they are probably done in a non standard way (perhaps with an `onclick` handler) which QTP is not familiar with, you will have to inspect your application yourself. A handy way to do so would be to [`RegisterUserFunc`](http://www.advancedqtp.com/add-new-methods-to-objects/) a new `IsDisabled` method to the `Link` test object and then use `GetROProperty` or `.Object` to understand whether the link is disabled.

Comment: I agree with Motti. Also, I´ve seen GUIs that contain a certain DIV element if a certain link is disabled. You could check for such a specific GUI circumstance, which totally depends on your application GUI (no specific app-independent advice available).